# How do I remove white-space from map-canvas?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3, whitespace

I'm looking to align this map with some content I have under it in another row but I can't seem to figure out how to remove the left and right white-space, (and keep it responsive)

http://www.bootply.com/QpCcKAQhBu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the Bootstrap class *col-md-8* which add

```
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
```

You should override that. For example, you can add

```
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
```

to your *mapRow* class

Here is the **[example](http://www.bootply.com/EPBQIOgJmO)**

Comment: I must have something else going wrong, it worked in Bootply but not on my local site. Do you know any possible reason why? Do I have to put up all my code on bootply?

Comment: Probably some other class override your changes. You can add
`style = "padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;"` to the div which has the map